# Numbering of figures with {figure*}

Tags: floats

I need to use both `figure` and `figure*` In my `twocolumn` article, but I have problems with the numbering. The figures are not numbered by the order of appearance. Apparently, the large `figures*` are the problem. Any suggestions, please?

I am using

```
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
```

and

```
\begin{figure}[h]
```

Comment: can you please add a compilable example? `[ht!]` have no sense with `figure*`

Comment: This is common inside a `twocolumn`-style document when mixing floats and non-floats. You may have to resort to shuffling content around, or numbering them manually...

Comment: @touhami ...and that migth be the issue, Could you please elaborate why exactly?

Comment: `figure*` can go only in `top` or in `only float page`

Comment: see here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Comment: in current latex releases the order of figures is preserved even if some are single and some are double, in older releases (before latex2e 2015/01/01) then you need `\RequirePackage[fixltx2e}` at the start of the docuemnt.

Comment: note you can not use `h` with `figure*` and `[h]` will usually give a warning, it is best to use `[htp]`